# View pager showing empty

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 5 fragments which I wanna use a view pager and slide through. When I run the app , there are 5 slidable activities , but all of them are blank.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));

}

public static class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Blood.java

```
public class Blood extends Fragment {

public Blood(){}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_blood, container, false);

    String [] pname = {"Dil Kapoor","Kunal Sharma","Manish Jumle","Vikram Sharma","Varun Surya",
            "Vishant","Varsha","Vivek Rawat","Deepak Duggal","Vikas Chauhan","Piyush Pachori","Vishesh Sagar","Ramesh Kumar Jain","Pooja Sethi","Dusmanta Nayak"};
    String [] phno={"Ph: 9810383305","Ph: 9911090955","Ph: 7053029216","Ph: 9717709787","Ph: 9910308217","Ph: 9958893461","Ph: 9999106564","Ph: 8527063021","Ph: 9910026715","Ph: 9999597059","Ph: 9654758509","Ph: 9999991434","Ph: 9910350461","Ph: 9868091610","Ph: " +
            "9250079218"};
    String [] btype = {"Blood Group: O+","Blood Group: AB-","Blood Group: AB+","Blood Group: A+","Blood Group: A+","Blood Group: AB-","Blood Group: B-","Blood Group: AB+","Blood Group: O-","Blood Group: O+","Blood Group: A1B+","Blood Group: AB-","Blood Group: B-","Blood Group: A1B-","Blood Group: A+"};
    String[] pincode ={"110059","110058","110058","110059","110058","110056","110059","110058","110059","110060","110059","110060","110059","110058","110060"};


    ArrayList<BloodObject> marray = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewblood);
    LinearLayoutManager mlLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mlLinearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    for(int i=0;i<pname.length;i++)
    {
        marray.add(new BloodObject(pname[i],phno[i],pincode[i],btype[i]));

    }

    BloodAdapter mBloodAdapter  = new BloodAdapter(marray);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mBloodAdapter);

    return view;

}}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

FloatingActionMenu fabMenu;
FloatingActionButton fab_search, fab_traker, fab_cart, fab_symptoms, fab_refils, fab_remainder;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<CustomerHome> mList;
private CustomerHomePageAdapter mAdapter;

private String[] title = {"Order Medicines" , "Daily Use" , "Nutrition" , "Body Care" , "Baby Nutrition", "First Aid"};
private int[] imageResourceId = {R.drawable.ic_firstaid ,
        R.drawable.ic_baby ,
        R.drawable.ic_nutrition,
        R.drawable.ic_cosmetics,
        R.drawable.ic_nutrition,
        R.drawable.ic_presription

};

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<title.length ; i++)
    {
        mList.add(new CustomerHome(title[i],imageResourceId[i]));
    }


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new CustomerHomePageAdapter(getActivity() , mList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MainActivity.GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    fabMenu = (FloatingActionMenu) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_menu);

    fab_search = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_search);
    fab_traker = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_health_tracker);
    fab_cart = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_cart);
    fab_symptoms = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_symptoms);
    fab_refils = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_refils);
    fab_remainder = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_remainder);

    fab_remainder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Remainder Feature coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    fab_refils.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Refils Feature coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    fab_symptoms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Symptoms checker Feature coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    fab_traker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Health Tracker Feature coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    fab_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cart Feature coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    fab_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Search Feature coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    return view;

}}
```

Hospital.java

```
 public class Hospital extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_hospital, container, false);

    String hname[] ={"  AIIMS ","  Indraprastha Apollo Hospital","  Max Superspecialty Hospital","  Sir Ganga Ram Hospital","  Medanta - The Medicity",
            "  GB Pant Hospital","  Fortis Hospital","  Dr. Ram Manohar Lohia Hospital","  BLK Super Specialty Hospital","  Batra Hospital "};
    String hspec[] ={" SPECIALISATION: Gal Bladder/Kidney Transplant/Cardiologist"," SPECIALISATION: Kidney Transplant/Cardiologist/Spine Chord Specialist"," SPECIALISATION: Cardiologist/ Spine Chord Specialist/Neurologist"," SPECIALISATION: Neurologist/Orthopedic/Liver Transplant"," SPECIALISATION: Liver Transplant/Orthopedic/Cardiologist",
            " SPECIALISATION: Autograft/Skin Specialist/Spin Chord Specialist"," SPECIALISATION: Skin Specialist/Cardiologist/Cancer"," SPECIALISATION: Spine Chord Specialist/Skin Care/Orthopedic"," SPECIALISATION: Cardiologist/Skin Care/Spine Chord Specialist"," SPECIALISATION: Orthopedic/Cardiologist/Cancer"};
    int hpin[]  ={110029,110076,110017,110060,122001,110002,201301,110001,110005,110062};
    String hcontno[] ={" Ph: 18602583010"," Ph: +91-11-29871090/1091"," Ph: +91 11 4055 4055"," Ph: +91 11-25750000"," Ph: +91 124 414 1414"," Ph: +91 11 2323 4242"," Ph: +911204300222"," Ph: 011-23365525"," Ph: +91 11 3040 3040"," Ph: 91-11-2995 8747"};

    ArrayList<HospitalObject> marray = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    for(int i=0;i<hname.length;i++)
    {
        marray.add(new HospitalObject(hname[i],hspec[i],hpin[i],hcontno[i]));
    }

    HospitalAdapter mHospitalAdapter  = new HospitalAdapter(marray);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHospitalAdapter);

    return view;

}}
```

These are the only fragments which ive coded. The rest two fragments are blank
I have a big feeling that ive done something wrong in the fragments.

Please help me with this

CustomPagerAdapter.java

```
 public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
    collection.addView(layout);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ModelObject.values().length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];
    return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId()); }}
```

ModelObject.java

```
   public enum ModelObject {

HOME(R.string.home, R.layout.fragment_home),
BLOOD(R.string.blood, R.layout.activity_blood),
HOSPITAL(R.string.hospital, R.layout.activity_hospital),
NEWS(R.string.news, R.layout.activity_news),
ABOUT(R.string.about, R.layout.activity_about_customer);

private int mTitleResId;
private int mLayoutResId;

ModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
    mTitleResId = titleResId;
    mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
}

public int getTitleResId() {
    return mTitleResId;
}

public int getLayoutResId() {
    return mLayoutResId;
}}
```

Comment: post the code where you set up the view pager in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use support.v4 Fragment;FragmentActivity;FragmentManager;FragmentPagerAdapter;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = LogUtil.makeLogTag(MainActivity.class);

    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
    private ChageFragment chageFragment;
    private RankingFragment rankingFragment;
    private AntivirusFragment antivirusFragment;

    private ViewPager fragment_container;
    private RadioGroup rg_tab;
    private LocationInfoBean locatbean;
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();
        initViewPager();
        initListener();
    }

    private void initView() {
        fragment_container = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        rg_tab = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_tab);

        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        antivirusFragment = new AntivirusFragment();
        rankingFragment = new RankingFragment();
        chageFragment = new ChageFragment();

        fragList.add(homeFragment);
        fragList.add(chageFragment);
        fragList.add(rankingFragment);
        fragList.add(antivirusFragment);

    }

    private void initViewPager() {
        {
            MyFragmentPagerAdapter fAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());

            fragment_container.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
            fragment_container.setAdapter(fAdapter);
            fragment_container
                    .addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                                float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            switch (position) {
                            case 0:
                                rg_tab.check(R.id.rb_home);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                rg_tab.check(R.id.rb_chage);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                rg_tab.check(R.id.rb_ranking);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                rg_tab.check(R.id.rb_antivirus);
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                        }
                    });

            fragment_container.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    }

    private void initListener() {
        rg_tab.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.rb_home:
                    fragment_container.setCurrentItem(0);
                    break;
                case R.id.rb_chage:
                    fragment_container.setCurrentItem(1);
                    break;
                case R.id.rb_ranking:
                    fragment_container.setCurrentItem(2);
                    break;
                case R.id.rb_antivirus:
                    fragment_container.setCurrentItem(3);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private long aw;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        long time = new Date().getTime();
        if (time - this.aw < 2000) {
            finish();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }, 200);
        } else {
            this.aw = time;
            if (!isFinishing()) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.quithint),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }

    class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            return fragList.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragList.size();
        }

    }
}
```

it's maybe contain many error ,replace to you fragment.